# How can I make the user just enter numbers and try again in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, java.util.scanner

The program is supposed to work as follows, the program asks for a number and the user must enter it, in case the user enters a letter, a number less than 0 or does not enter anything, an error will appear and it will tell the user to try again, giving the user infinite attempts.

I have tried but I only get an infinite loop inside the catch, I would appreciate any help.

```java
public static void numbers(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        
        System.out.print("Enter only numbers: ");
        while(true){
            try {
                number = in.nextInt();
                if(number > 0){
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Try again: ");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print("Try again: ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader var = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        
    boolean response = false;
    
    while (!response) {  
        try {
            System.out.println("Input number: ");
            String input = var.readLine();
            int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
            response = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = false;
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: found you a simple solution. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, this is not the purpose of stackoverflow. But i would help you.

If you compare with other cmd processes always they ask for a y/N answer. So:

```
public static void numbers(Scanner overrideIn = null){
    Scanner in = overrideIn ?? new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    
    System.out.print("Enter only numbers: ");
    while(true){
        try {
            number = in.nextInt();
            if(number > 0){
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Try again: ");
                this.TryAgain(in);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("Try again: ");
            this.TryAgain(in);
        }
    }
public static void TryAgain(Scanner in)
{
    char respond = in.next().charAt(0);
    if (respond == 'y')
    {
        this.numbers(in);
    } else {
        System.out.print("See ya!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that if the input is not actually an integer, it stays in the scanner. Scanner does not advance at all to the next line or something.

So this invalid integer is blocking you from accessing something more, even if it were a number.

From the java doc:

> This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

So for unsuccessful translation, the problematic line STAYS, and next call to the nextInt method will fail as well, trying the parse the problematic line. Thus your infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 0;
while (n == 0) {
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    try {
        n = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Try again");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer to your question:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test {
  public static void numbers(){
    while(true){
      Scanner userInteraction = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter only numbers: ");
      String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();    
      if (userInput.matches("\\d+$")){
        double userNum = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        System.out.println("Congrats! You typed a number!");
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println("GRRR! You didn't type a number!");
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    numbers();
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image: Output]

**How it works:**

In order to check if the userInput is a number, you need to use a regex (or a **REG**ular **EX**pression). **I used the regex matcher** `\\d+$`. More info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680654/how-do-i-check-for-multiple-args-in-a-regex-with-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666495/how-do-i-check-for-args-in-a-userinput-command)! After verifying that the userInput was a number(with the regex matcher), I used the function `Integer.parseInt(userInput)` to change the String into an Integer. Then, I will congratulate the player and `break;` the loop. If the player fails to type a number, I will warn the player and `continue;` the loop.

Comment: You should not use screenshots when copying and pasting the text would suffice. Also, there is no need to write the "If this isn't your desired result, please leave a comment. I will revise my answer and provide what you need."

Comment: What if it isn't their desired result .-. They will downvote and I will not be able to help them.

Comment: People generally explain their down-votes. Also, looking at your code, it is better to not create a Scanner in each iteration of the loop, and instead reuse the same one. In this sense, Samudra's answer is cleaner.

Comment: Cool. I didn't learn about ```try..catch``` yet so I didn't use it in my answer.