# How do I check for specific parts in a userInput command?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a game.. and when someone types a command in the console, I would like there to be [args] in the command.

For example:

**~heal [username] [health]**

Here is an **example** code(refer to this if you have an answer):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class StackOverflowExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Healing Command: ~heal [username] [health]");
    int player1HP = 0;
    Scanner userInteraction = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
    if (userInput.equals("~heal " /**+ username + num**/) /**How do I make it so that a number(the amount to heal) and a username(player username) can be inputted after?**/){
      player1HP += 0; /**I need the number that the user inputs to be added to player1HP**/
    }
    System.out.println("player1/**I want this to be the username value**/ is at: " + player1HP/**I want this to be the hp value + player1HP**/ + " hp.");//I want this command to print out "ProGamer is at: 3 hp."
    
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**How do I get the values of "username" and "health"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to make sure that the input is valid.

You can then call method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to separate the command into its separate words.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflowExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Healing Command: ~heal [username] [health]");
        int player1HP = 0;
        Scanner userInteraction = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
        if (userInput.matches("^~heal [^ ]+ \\d+$")) {
            String[] parts = userInput.split(" ");
            int health = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            player1HP += health;
            String player = parts[1];
            System.out.printf("%s is at: %d hp.%n", player, player1HP);
        }
    }
}
```

The regular expression checks that the entered command begins with `~heal` followed by a single space followed by one or more characters that are not a space followed by another space followed by one or more digits.

Then the entered command is split on the spaces which returns a three element array where the first array element is the command (i.e. `~heal`), the second element is the player name and the last element is the amount of health.

Comment: Hi, can you explain to me what each part of ```^~heal [^ ]+ \\d+$``` means?  Also, how would I only test for ~heal [username] without the number? I tried removing \\d but it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @FairOPShotgun _can you explain to me what each part of `^~heal [^ ]+ \\d+$` means?_ I did, in the first sentence after the code in my answer. _Also, how would I only test for ~heal [username] without the number?_ Try `userInput.matches("^~heal [^ ]+ .+$")` By the way, did you read the Web pages I provided links to in my answer?

Answer (score -2):

Do a split.

```
userInput.split(" ")
```