# How do I check for multiple [args] in a regex with Java?

Tags: java, regex, console, command, java.util.scanner

I am making a console game.. and I want to be able to check for 2 people's information at the same time. In my case, I want to make a "kill checker" command. The command is

```
~killc [username]
```

With this command, I would be able to check 1 person's kills. What if I want to check 2 people? How would I use my .matches(regex) to figure 2 Strings? I have tried typing:

```
"^~killc [^ ] [^ ]+$", and "^~killc [^ ] + [a-zA-Z]+$"
```

but they don't work.
Read my code below for more information.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class StackOverflowExample {
  static int kills = 10;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Kill count command: ~killc [username]");
    Scanner userInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = userInt.nextLine();
    if (userInput.matches("^~killc [^ ]+$"/**How would I input more than one username?**/)){
      String[] parts = userInput.split(" ");
      String username = parts[1];
      System.out.printf("%s has " + kills + " kills.",username);
      
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this "not work"? Are you getting an error message, an unexpected output, or something more concrete than "doesn't work"?

Comment: @NickReed Nothing happens. I play the code, and it just ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capture group, and split the value of the capture group on a space.

```
^~killc (\S+(?: \S+)*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `~killc\h+` Match `~killc` and 1+ spaces
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S+(?:\h+\S+)*` Match 1+ non whitspace chars, and optionally repeat 1+ spaces and 1+ non whitspace chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFJsCq/1)

```
System.out.println("Kill count command: ~killc [username]");
Scanner userInt = new Scanner(System.in);
String regex = "^~killc\\h+(\\S+(?:\\h+\\S+)*)$";
String userInput = userInt.nextLine();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userInput);

if (matcher.find()) {
    for (String username : matcher.group(1).split(" "))
        System.out.printf("%s has " + kills + " kills.\n",username);
}
```

If the input is `~killc test1 test2`

The output will be

```
Kill count command: ~killc [username]
test1 has 10 kills.
test2 has 10 kills.
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/p81QW9)

Answer (score 0):

How about a repeated group?

`^~killc(?: [^ ]+)+$`

This will capture one or more usernames when put into the command. Actually parsing them is up to you, but if the usernames are well formatted, this will catch them.
Personally, I'd be very careful around `[^ ]+` since it's going to accept a newline as a match; try `\S+` instead if it's available, which will match anything that's not whitespace.